# Find contacts on CiviCRM

Tags: contacts

Good morning,

Every time I search for a contact, which I know is on our database, I get the message 'No contact found'.

Please can you advise?

Many thanks

Kind regards

Myriam Barker

Comment: What fields are you using to search

Comment: are you searching with the necessary format ie <lastname>, <firstname> eg Davis, Peter, not Peter Davis

Answer (score 3):

(Adding this answer based on Comment by Myriam)

This could be a Permission issue. If the contact is in the db but you do not have permission to see them then you won't see any results.

Ways to confirm this would be use the QuickSearch and just hit ENTER (or type % and hit Enter if the former has no effect), do you see all the results of contacts, ie your complete list.

If you do and you still do not find them, then you may also need to search in Trash

If you only see a subset of your contacts then there could be some ACL that is restricting which contacts you can see

If you only see your record, then it is likely to be civicrm Permissions which are set by your CMS

Comment: FYI I saw in chat the other day that the quicksearch+enter feature has been taken out. Didn't sound intentional but a side effect of the new menu, but there was limited interest in trying to put back.

Comment: yep i got annoyed about that today, then figured I could just enter % and hit enter. updated answer to reflect that

Comment: Oh that's interesting. But then how would you search for people or orgs who have % in their names! I don't know of any but there's "Yahoo!" and people like this https://www.strategyand.pwc.com. I'm (partly) kidding of course.

Comment: Thanks, all. I was added as an administrator, and I haven't had any issues since then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the contact search in the upper right corner, be sure that the correct radio select is checked. For example, if you are searching for Judy, be sure that Name/Email. Or searching Chicago, be sure that City is checked.

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing your search? What are you searching for?

For instance, I often use the quick search box in the top left. I may be searching based on their ID, but have the name/email option selected.

Or I search on a name and do it wrong. For instance, to look up Judy Smith, you would type in: Smith, Judy

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jenni's comments, and I also suspect that you are using search incorrectly. To use her example, if you put in "Judy Smith" it would not find her. Have you tried part of the name: "judy" or "smith" both of which should work. That works for either the quick search box or "Find Contacts".

The more information you give, the more likely people will be able to help.

Comment: Yes, I do all this, and I am not the only one in our organisation having issues searching for contacts, when we were all absolutely fine before. Thanks

Comment: Very odd... Will definitely need more to work out what is wrong.
a) make sure you and another person are trying exactly the same search
b) try from another persons system with your log in (and vice versa) to decide if its your local environment or your account.

Comment: My colleague had to add me as an administrator and it's all fine now - thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few days ago. And the contact I was looking for was me. So I knew I was there.

it might be a caching issue locally or at server level.

If you can clear the civicrm cache sitename/civicrm/clearcache

Clear cache in the content management system

and finally clear browser cache locally

One of those sorted it for me.